# Twitter Bootstrap - Navbar with second level, but not a dropdown

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I want to make a top navbar with a second level, but not as a dropdown menu. It should apear as a second row under the first one. Example (* means the is the active one):

nav1 | nav2* | nav3

nav2a | nav2b

Should look like this:

```
<div class="navbar" id="topnavi">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <ul class="nav">
            <li>
                <a href="#">nav1</a>
                <ul class="secondlevel">
                    <li><a href="#">nav1a</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">nav1b</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">nav1c</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">nav2</a>
                <ul class="secondlevel">
                    <li><a href="#">nav2a</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">nav2b</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">nav3</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe give the second level menu a class and override it's css to float:left and vetical align:top ? Need to make sure the selector is targeting specific to make it work.

Comment: I'd just stack two .navbar on top of each other, don't nest them together

Answer (score 1):

I used the dropdown class and over-wrote some of the styles so that the nested dropdown items appear as a secondary nav below the primary items. This is the general direction from what I understand- hope it helps!

HTML:

```
    <div class="navbar">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
          <ul class="nav">
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown</a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown</a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
    .nav > li {
         display: inline-block;
     }
    .dropdown-menu{
         display: inline;
         position: relative;
     }
     .dropdown-menu > li{
         display:inline-block;
     }
```